# Positioning shape at the edge of the screen

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift-playground

Given a PlaygroundBook page, how can you position a SpriteKit node to the right edge of the screen of the `liveView` so it "snaps" there?

So far I've tried to position the node like so:

```
// Context: class _: SKScene 
// myNode.frame.size == CGSize(width: self.frame.width / 4, height: self.frame.height)

myNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.maxX - myNode.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.frame.midY)
```

If I were to position the node at `CGPoint(x: self.frame.maxX, y: self.frame.midY)`, I would expect its center to be right at the right edge of the screen, cropping out half of the node: that **doesn't** happen, the node gets placed someplace where it isn't visible at all.

Additionally:

- the node positions right in the middle if I were to use `frame.midX` as the `x` coordinate
- the node positions at the bottom-left corner of the screen if I were to use `(0, 0)` as the position.

What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: (0,0) is center of the scene, so (-midx,-midy) is top left, (midx,midy) is bottom right

Comment: Updated the answer. `(midX, midY)` positions right at the center.

Comment: What are you using for your scene size?

Comment: `(self.view as! SKView).bounds.size`, `self.view` is the ViewController's object.

Comment: hmmm,  I wonder if the view size is the same size as the liveView window

Comment: I've just printed the `view.bounds.size` for both `.sideBySide` and `.fullScreen` and it seems to be identical; same for `(midX, midY)`... if, however, you rotate the iPad with the node being at `(midX, midY)` it repositions automatically to the center of the screen... ? What?

Comment: that is definitely weird,  change the scalemode to `.fill`, and see if things pop up.  It feels like you are getting cropping from `.aspectFill`, but I do not understand why you would be.

Comment: For both `.fill` and `.aspectFill` the `(midX, midY)` values don't change... this is pure black magic.

Comment: well the value wouldnt change, but it should display on the screen

Comment: To which class does `myNode` belong? If it is an SKSpriteNode, you can use the `anchorPoint` property to manipulate where the sprite node should be positioned.

Comment: @JoRa SKShapeNode.